# Solve the system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I found system of equations on internet, I want to practice math and to solve it.

**All $x$,$y$ and $z$ are integers.**

$$\begin{cases}
x+y+z=3 \\
x^3+y^3+z^3=3
\end{cases}
$$

Should I start by watching all combinations that sum up to 3, please give me some hint to start.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ integers?

Comment: We can see that x=1, y=1 and z=1 works.That solves the system.

Comment: Yes $x,y,z are integers.

Comment: Positive integers ?

Comment: @JeanMarie seems to be a basic system of equations from an Algebra course, that usually implies all real numbers.

Comment: @Heavenly96, the OP already answered that $x,y,z$ are integers (see above comment).  So don't correct JeanMarie.

Comment: Nice find, @DietrichBurde.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx). $$
Then since $x+y+z=3=x^3+y^3+z^3 $, thus we need to solve
$$1-xyz=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx .$$

Comment: This is a well-known identity. I used it several times in high school

Comment: do you remember this: if sum of three numbers is zero, then the some of cubes of them is equal to 3 times their product?

Comment: @user420255 It seems that not all of us had such an enriched high school experience... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for solutions with $x,y,z$ real, then you can just substitue $z=3-x-y$ in the second equation to find
$$
y=\frac{-9+6x-x^2\pm\sqrt{x^4-18x^2+32x-15}}{2x-6} \\
z = 3-x-y \\
 x\leq -5 \mbox{ or }x=1\mbox{ or }x\geq 3
$$
(The quartic inside the square root is easy to factor because $x=1$ is a double root.)

So that is a set of three curves, one each in quadrants I, II, and IV.

If you are looking for solutions with $x,y,z\in \Bbb Z$ this immediately gives
$$
\{x=1,y=1,z=1\}, \{x=-5,y=4,z=4\}
$$
and by symmetry you get two others that lie along the curves in the first and second quadrants
$$\{x=4,y=-5,z=4\},\{x=4,y=4,z=-5\}$$

So now we need to wonder whether there are any other integer solutions.

For that to happen, a necessary (but perhaps not sufficient) condition is that 
$$
x^4-18x^2+32x-15=k^2$$
for some integer $k\not\in \{0,3,4\}$.

We can show that this cannot happen, as follows:

For $x\geq 5$, 
$$
 (x^2-1)^2 < x^4-18x^2+32x-15 + 16(x^2-1)^2 <x^4-18x^2+32x-15 < x^4=(x^2)^2
$$
so x$^4-18x^2+32x-15$ lies striclty between two consecutive integers.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete solution see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312183/find-all-integral-solutions-to-xyz-3-x3y3z3-3).So let me just add a comment.
There is a stronger conjecture, namely that the Diophantine equation
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=3
$$
only has $(1,1,1)$ and $(4,4,-5)$ and its permutations as integral solutions, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58188/are-nontrivial-integer-solutions-known-for-x3y3z3-3). Cassels showed that any integral solution $(x,y,z)$ has to satisfy
$$
x\equiv y\equiv z \bmod 9.
$$
Furthermore, [Oppenheim](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-02/S0002-9939-1966-0188151-0/S0002-9939-1966-0188151-0.pdf) studied the Diophantine equation
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=x+y+z.
$$

Comment: OP wants an undergraduate level answer, but yours is quite advanced when you quoted " Oppenheim"'s work from an article. OP probably get lost reading your answer.

Comment: @DeepSea The duplicate gives already an elementary answer. My answer hence is just a comment, for someone interested in Diophantine equations. The OP may actually perhaps enjoy a bit more background on number theory. The statements are really elementary!